# Can't change the state using computed setter in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I need to submit a form using computed property in Vue.js. The `end_saving` is computed from `start_saving` and `duration`. I need to use `saving.end_saving` in `v-model` so I can submit the value in a POST method via Axios.

```
<template>
......
 <b-form-datepicker
   locale="id"
   :value="endSaving"
   @input="saving.end_saving= $event.target.value"
  ></b-form-datepicker>
......
</template>
....
data() {
 return {
  saving: {
    start_saving: "",
    duration: "",
    end_saving: "",
  },
computed: {
 endSaving: {
  get: function () {
    return moment(this.saving.start_saving)
      .add(this.saving.duration, "days")
      .subtract(1, "days")
      .format("YYYY-MM-DD");
  },
  set: function (newValue) {
    return (this.saving.end_saving = newValue);
  },
},
},
methods: {
 submitForm() {
  axios
    .post("/api/saving", this.saving)
    .then(
      (response) =>
        (window.location.href = `/saving/${response.data.id}`)
    )
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
 },
}
```

But, every time I submit the form, the `end_saving` is always `null`.

Comment: This is pretty confusing. Which properties should be editable by the user in the UI? Where are `start_saving` and `duration` assigned values?

Comment: I feel like your [setter](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter) for `endSaving` should just be `set: function(newValue) {this.saving.end_saving = newValue}`. Not tested this yet.

Comment: @Phil ya there are input form for start_saving and duration

Comment: @Phil There are 3 inputs in form, start_saving, duration, and end_saving. end_saving readonly value, the value is from start_saving + duration. So user just can input to start saving and duration

Comment: If it's read-only, why have you added a date-picker for it?

Comment: @Phil oh yes, that should not date-picker.

Comment: What's the point in posting both `duration` **and** `end_saving`? Can't the server-side process compute the end date for itself based on start and duration?

Comment: @Phil ya, i think it should handled in server side rather than client side

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you would be better off computing the entire `savings` object.

For example

```js
data: () => ({
  start_saving: "",
  duration: 0
}),
computed: {
  saving: ({ start_saving, duration }) => ({
    start_saving,
    duration,
    end_saving: moment(start_saving).add(duration - 1, "days").format("YYYY-MM-DD")
  })
}
```

Then bind your two form inputs to `start_saving` and `duration`

```html
<b-form-datepicker
  locale="id"
  v-model="start_saving"
></b-form-datepicker>

<input type="number" v-model.number="duration">
```

and use `this.saving` in your Axios POST request (like you currently have)

```js
axios.post("/api/saving", this.saving)
```